# How do I flatten a hierarchical column index in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a hierarchical index on the columns as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB'), list('ab')])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((2,4)), columns=columns)
print df
```

Out[1]:

```
   A     B   
   a  b  a  b
0  0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6  7
```

I would like to flatten the column index so it looks as follows:

```
   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

I tried

```
def flatten(col):
    col.name = ''.join(col.name)
    return col

df.apply(f)
```

but that just ignored the modified name of the new columns.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### `set_axis`

```
df.set_axis([f"{x}{y}" for x, y in df.columns], axis=1, inplace=False)

   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

---

#### `index.map`

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
df

   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

---

#### For non-string column values

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: ''.join([*map(str, x)]))
df

   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

Comment: I like the rename version the best but it doesn't work for me in version 0.16.1.

Comment: I'm running into issues with `df.columns.map(''.join)` with `int` type column indexes.

Comment: Will check it out.  Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I might have a solution. It looks like column labels can be of type int.

Comment: @dreyco676 when of type `int` the solution is different

Comment: `df.columns = (''.join(str(col)) for col in df.columns.values)` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `list comprehension` with `join`:

```
df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

Another possible solution:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().str.join('')
print (df)
   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```

Comment: Hi could you help answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395699/how-to-drop-row-index-and-flatten-index-in-this-way)

Answer (score 0):

The following works but creates a new `DataFrame`:

```
df_flat = pd.DataFrame({''.join(k):v for k,v in df.iteritems()})
print df_flat
```

Out[3]:

```
   Aa  Ab  Ba  Bb
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
```