# Concatenate 2 Rows to be header/column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel sheet that is really poorly formatted. The actual column names I would like to use are across two rows; For example, if the correct column name should be `Labor Percent`, cell `A1` would contain `Labor`, and cell `A2` would contain `Percent`).

I try to load the file, here's what I'm doing:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r'xxx')

import pandas as pd

file = 'problem.xls'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
print(xl.sheet_names)

df = xl.parse('WEEKLY NUMBERS', skiprows=35)
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the remainder of what should be the column name is in the second row. Is there a way to rename the columns by concatenating? Can this somehow be done with the `header=` argument in the `xl.parse` bit?

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the columns yourself by setting:

```
df.columns = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3' ...]
```

Note that you must specify a name for every column.

Then drop the first row to get rid of the unwanted row of column names.

```
df = df.drop(0)
```

Comment: I think there's probably 30+ columns...I was looking more for a way to do it formulaically...Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try. Essentially it reads in the first two rows as your header, but treats it as a hierarchical multi-index. The second line of code below then flattens that multi-index down to a single string. I'm not 100% certain it will work for your data but is worth a try - it worked for the small dummy test data I tried it with:

```
df = pd.read_excel('problem.xlsx', sheetname='WEEKLY NUMBERS', header=[0, 1])
df.columns = df.columns.map(' '.join)
```

The second line was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931332/how-do-i-flatten-a-hierarchical-column-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe) answer about flattening a multi-index.